# Function not firing using .click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fire a function on a click event using $(this) perhaps to capture the event and fire a function. I have tried various methods, but still getting error in firebug about

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

I would be grateful if someone could explain how to achieve this based on my code. Many thanks

```
$(function() { 
$("#box_frtv").chosen({

 width: "250px",
 max_selected_options: 1

 });
 $("#box_frtv").bind("chosen:maxselected",

            // Only want this function to fire onclick event. something like $(this).click( 
            function() {

            $("#boxerror").freeow("ERROR", "sample error message", {
                classes: ["gray", "error"],
                autoHide: true
            });
          });
        });
```

**UPDATED CODE** still errors.

```
$(function() { 
    $("#box_frtv").chosen({
        width: "250px",
        max_selected_options: 1
    });

    $("#box_frtv").bind("chosen:maxselected",
        // Only want this function to fire onclick event. something like  
        $(this).click( function() {
            $("#boxerror").freeow("ERROR", "sample error message", {
                classes: ["gray", "error"],
            autoHide: true
            });
        });
    }); 
});
```

html

```
<div class="fieldset">
            <h1><span>Select Your Box(es)</span></h1>
            <p>
              <select data-placeholder="Choose your box(es)..." class="chosen-select" name="box_frtv[]" id="box_frtv" multiple required="required">
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php
                  do {

                  ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row_rs_fbrtv['boxref']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rs_fbrtv['boxref']; ?></option>
                <?php
                  } while ($row_rs_fbrtv = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_fbrtv));

                  $rows = mysql_num_rows($rs_fbrtv);

                  if($rows > 0) {

                  mysql_data_seek($rs_fbrtv, 0);

                  $row_rs_fbrtv = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_fbrtv);

                  }

                  ?>
              </select><span id="boxerror" class="freeow freeow-bottom-right"></span><div id="boxError"></div>
            </p>
          </div>
```

Comment: }); missing of $(function){

Comment: deleted my answer as it wasn't correct, and i can't help you with the actual problem you're having.

Comment: You need to be clearer about what effect you are trying to produce. Is your requirement that once the `chosen:maxselected` event occurs you want to _then_ bind a click event handler to that same element? Or are you trying to _trigger_ a click event at that point? Or...?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$(function() { 
    $("#box_frtv").chosen({
        width: "250px",
        max_selected_options: 1
    });

    $("#box_frtv").bind("chosen:maxselected",function(){
        // Only want this function to fire onclick event. something like  
        $(this).click( function()
        {
            $("#boxerror").freeow("ERROR", "sample error message",
            {
                classes: ["gray", "error"],
                autoHide: true
            });
        });
    });

 });
```

You have written `$("#box_frtv").bind("chosen:maxselected",`  instead of `$("#box_frtv").bind("chosen:maxselected",function(){` .

If this solves your problem!

Comment: @Nivdeita Dosen't fire at all when i click. No errors reported. Thanks

Comment: can you post your html?? you may also consider using .on() instead of .bind() ...
Also which jquery version are you using?

Comment: since as of jQUERY 1.7 onwards .on() is the preferred method for attaching handlers

Comment: Posted html as requested.

Comment: @user1532468 What do you expect to happen on click??

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the callback code inside a function like this:

```
$("#box_frtv").bind("chosen:maxselected", function() {
    $(this).click();
});
```

In order to trigger the click event the click() function can't have any arguments. So instead you can bind the callback function to the click event:

```
$("#box_frtv").bind("click", function() {
    $("#boxerror").freeow("ERROR", "sample error message", {
        classes: ["gray", "error"],
        autoHide: true
    });
});
```